# Maintaining Product Specification for web application

Tags: e-commerce

My project is about selling a product from different stores online.
I am not using any framework because it is not the client requirement.

I want to know which is best way of allowing stores to add their product, as the different products have different specification: Clothing have different specifications then Electronics and even different electronics categories have different features.

Do I have to create the form or structure for all the different products which looks impossible or there is other better way ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not programming question at all still would like to answer it base on your conditions

1. Use a form if,

   - You have limited set of inventory and stores.
2. Use feed system if you are not certain of the limits,

   - Lets customer create a feed of the products they have. Develop a feed import logic with generalized product properties and upload the feeds.
   - The already developed feed import logic will import and update product data in your server.

For product feed you can refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_feed